# What is this part used for? 2x4 plate with a round bit sticking out with a hole

Tags: part-identification

I have 4 of these pieces they are marked Pat Pend. Does any one know what these pieces are? [image: 2x4 plate with round bit]

Answer (score 3):

BrickLink calls it a [train coupler](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=737bc01). So it's for trains. (It might also be [a closed variant](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=737c01), I can't tell from the photo.)